# Делегирование событий — обработка дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь сделать делегирование событий на чистом JS. У меня есть кнопка внутри контейнера:

```
<div id="quiz">
  <button id="game-again" class="game-again"><span class="icon-spinner icon"></span><span>Go again</span></button>
</div>
```

Следуя [инструкциям Дэвида Уолша](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate), я добавляю обработчик события на родителя кнопки таким образом:

```
this.container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (e.target && e.target.id == 'game-again') {
      e.stopPropagation();
      self.publish('primo:evento');
  }
});
```

Где `this.container` это элемент `#quiz`. Это работает в половине случаев, но в остальных `target` события клика это один из спанов внутри кнопки, потому обработчик события не срабатывает. Как исправить ситуацию?

---

*ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117369/vanilla-js-event-delegation-dealing-with-child-elements-of-the-target-element*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Современные браузеры

Современные браузеры поддерживают [`.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches):

```
this.container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (e.target.matches('#game-again, #game-again *')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    self.publish('primo:evento');
  }
});
```

Для большей поддержки браузеров, можете получить версию без префиксов

```
var matches = document.body.matchesSelector || document.body.webkitMatchesSelector || document.body.mozMatchesSelector || document.body.msMatchesSelector || document.body.webkitMatchesSelector || document.body.matchesSelector
```

и потом использовать при помощи `.apply` (IE9+).

### Старые браузеры

Если вам необходимо поддерживать более старые браузеры, метод такой: пройтись вверх по дереву DOM.

```
function hasInParents(el, id){
  if(el.id === id) return true; // элемент
  if(element.parentNode) return hasInParents(el.parentNode,id); // родитель
  return false; // не элемент и не родитель
}
```

Однако, таким образом будет перебираться DOM целиком, а вам необходимо остановиться у вашего элемента:

```
function hasInParentsUntil(el,id,limit){
  if(el.id === id) return true; // элемент
  if(el === limit) return false;
  if(element.parentNode) return hasInParents(el.parentNode,id); // родитель
  return false; // не элемент и не родитель
}
```

И код будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
this.container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (hasInParentsUntil(e.target, 'game-again', container)) {
      e.stopPropagation();                                  
      self.publish('primo:evento');
  }
});
```